# Will images included in a comment remain available

Tags: support, comment, images

I just wanted to write [a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85793/symbolic-coordinates-for-a-hyperbolic-grid/247477#comment560038_247477) with reference to an image. As comments won't allow inline images, I uploaded the image to an edit window of some other post, canceled the edit there, and included the URL in the comment instead. Now I wonder whether this image is going to stay around, or whether it will vanish in the near future after some automated process finds out that no core post includes that image. Can you tell me?

Comment: Just want to say thank you for the idea to upload images in an edit pane before including them in comments.  I've been uploading them directly to imgur until now, but this will ensure they don't get accidentally deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/) the images uploaded from StackExchange will stay on Imgur as long as StackExchange keeps up their pro account.